# How to print Zebra image using ZPL commands in Java not on zebra printer

Tags: java, zpl

I am new to Zebra printer stuff. I have got my ZPL commands. I need some Java API which can convert ZPL commands in Zebra printer format and need to print on console.

I have researched on this but I got so many approaches to send to Zebra printer.

I also got http://labelary.com/viewer.html. But I want to generate sticker output from ZPL commands using Java and in Java only at console. Please suggest me a approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at this Java library (credit goes to the creator **w3blogfr**): https://github.com/w3blogfr/zebra-zpl

You may want to use **ZebraNativeZpl** function from this library to parse your ZPL commands and add it to **ZebraLabel** object since you already got your ZPL commands.

After you obtain your ZebraLabel object, there is a method **getImagePreview**() to generate preview image. But the content position in preview image could be different than what it actually is when printing it via Zebra printer.

Alternatively, you could try to send your ZPL commands to the web service offered by labelary.com (http://labelary.com/service.html) and display the result at where you want.

Comment: Yes I need to preview my generated ZPL code with simulated result similar to labelary.com.